# Should i cut my hands off?

Tags: practical-islam, theft

I stole some money from my parents. They don't give me any pocket money or at least a dime . They ask me to go to the the shop and buy stuff. I used to buy the stuff and keep the balance if they forget to take it from me.

Is this a sin  ? I didnt realize its magnitude then . Should I cut of my hands  ?

I must have stolen about 10 dollars. I read a  Hadees somewhere that says that the Hands shouldn't be cut off for theft worth less than 10 Dirhams or Dinars or summat.

Should I cut my hands off  ?

Comment: Cutting the hand is done by the state when the thief has been caught and convicted and certain requirements are fulfilled regarding the theft. Embezzling of your parents money is not theft of the kind that is eligible for hadd.

Comment: Be aware that steeling or more properly taking money or wealth from parents or children etc. is not punished by default according to shari'a (I'm not aware if it is punished at all for the named cases). As it might be a due of either parents or children to be in charge for the other, which means that they have a right over some of their wealth. As long as there is doubt that a certain person has a right over some wealth punishment can't apply for a thief.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the punishment for stealing from my parents?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/51732/what-is-the-punishment-for-stealing-from-my-parents)

Answer (score 1):

Any hadd punishment (Such as for stealing, murder, etc.) can only be done by the proper authorities. I recommend you ask forgiveness from Allah and return any money you stole from your parents. If you spent the money, then you should get a job and work for the money so you can return it. If you fear your parents would no longer trust you, then perhaps it is best if you return it without them knowing, like placing it in their wallet or something like this while they do not know. However, I strongly advise you NOT to cut off your hand, as only the ruler can do this and should NOT be done by lay people. I would be very surprised if your parents would want your hands to be cut off for you stealing $10 from them.

And Allah knows best.

Answer (score -2):

You must discuss this with your parents. There is a process if your parents don't forgive you.It is up to them if they want to punish you or not.